# Unable to find tools.jar in JDK in Ubuntu

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk

I have used the following command to install openjdk

`sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk`

But there seems to be no `lib/tools.jar` present. I am sure that it is the jdk that I have downloaded and not the jre. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong. `tools.jar` was removed in JDK 9. From [JEP 220: Modular Run-Time Images](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220):

> ***Removed: rt.jar and tools.jar***

---

**Related post**: [How to get tools.jar for OpenJDK 11 on Windows? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53707666/10785056)